# How to access resources from another proyect

Tags: c#-4.0, localization

I have two resource files called String.arg.resx and String.en.rex in a proyect called Common

Then I Have a class called LocalizationService in my Service proyect, the code is as follows:

```
public class LocalizationService
{
    private ResourceManager resourceManager;
    private CultureInfo cultureInfo;

    public LocalizationService()
    {
        SetDefaultCultureAndResource();       
    }

    private void SetDefaultCultureAndResource()
    {
        cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en");
        resourceManager = new ResourceManager("Common.Resources.String", Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Common.Resources));
    }

    public void ChangeLanguage(Languages languages)
    {
        switch (languages)
        {
            case Languages.Español:
                cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es");
                resourceManager = new ResourceManager("Common.Resources.String", typeof(LocalizationService).Assembly);
                break;
            case Languages.English:
                cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en");
                break;
            default:
                cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en");
                break;
        }
    }

    public string GetString(string value)
    {
        return resourceManager.GetString(value, cultureInfo);
    }

}
```

But the line `resourceManager = new ResourceManager("Common.Resources.String", Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Common.Resources));` is not working, because I dont see Common.Resources.

Which Method of the Assembly class I should be using?

Answer (score 0):

Ok... It seems I found the answer, I just put a Class that is inside the assembly where the Resource files are.